# I need text to stay inside a container without using the <br> tag over and over

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my text to stay inside my box without going outside of it.
I don't want to use the `<br>` tag over and over. So I am trying to make it so it makes a new line automatically.

**CSS**

```
#NewsPosts {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: -925px;
    font-size: 20px; 
    margin-left: 10; 
    margin-right: 10; 
    text-indent: 5; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!--NewsPosts-->
<div id="NewsPosts">
    <div align = "center">
        <p>html text goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example:

[image: http://puu.sh/cEWrV/ffe4b7e4cc.jpg]

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You don't close `<div align="center">`.

Comment: @royhowie OP is closing it, it's just not indented correctly.

Comment: giving us the full code of the page would help us more as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `width` CSS property:

```
#example-autowrap{
    width:40%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/91efphoL/ is a working example of this

To make it fit into your background like in the image link you posted, just make sure that the element containing text is a child of the background element, and it should work, with or without the `width`

If you want it to be centered, and for some reason you CAN'T put it as a child of the background element, then you should just add `margin:0 auto`. This attempts to set both the right and left margins to the same value, effectively centering it

Comment: And if you add `margin: 0 auto;` it will even be centered (like in the screenshot).

Comment: yeah, but I'm assuming he can deal with that himself, this question is about line breaks, not centering

Comment: As you see from the other answer's comment, that's not the case. ;)

Comment: well, he/she should be putting it as a child of whatever background element there is. I'll edit it anyway with the margin trick

Answer (score 2):

```
#NewsPosts p{
   width:40%
   word-break:break-all;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/91efphoL/1/

Comment: Add `margin: 0 auto;` (assuming the box is centered).

Answer (score 0):

You could just use something like overflow if you dont mind the menu bar

```
#NewsPosts {
position: relative;
bottom: 0px;
top: -925px;
font-size: 20px; 
margin-left: 10; 
margin-right: 10; 
text-indent: 5; 
overflow-y:scroll; 
}
```

Or just and us padding and margins to center your text

```
#NewsPosts p{
   width:40%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mention "width:50%;" in the #NewsPosts and its all done.